# How to count the occurrence of a character in each word of a string ignoring its case?

Tags: python, list

I have a string, say `Welcome to this world`. I need to count the occurrence of the character `w` ignoring its case whether it is upper or lower.

```py
x = "Welcome to this world"
list = x.split()
print(list)
a = []

for i in list:
    a.append(i.count("w"))
else:
    print(a)
```

> **Output:**
>       ['Welcome', 'to', 'this', 'world']
>       [0,0,0,1]

This gives output as `[0,0,0,1]` but I want it to be `[1,0,0,1]` if the case of `w` is ignored. What changes should I make ?

Comment: This sounds amazingly like homework. If so, "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)" is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to count every character that is either `w` or `W`, you can use this simple one-liner:

```
x = "Welcome to this world"
print(x.lower().count("w"))
```

output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `lower()`

```py
x = "Welcome to this world"
list = x.split()
print(list)
a = []

for i in list:
    a.append(i.lower().count("w"))
else:
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lower` as mentioned - you can also do this more succinctly

```
ws_in_words = [word.count('w') for word in x.lower().split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

A way you can do it is just iterate through the entire string, it can be done like this:

```
str = "Welcome to this world"
index = 0
occurOfW = 0
for char in range(len(str)):
    if str[index] == 'w':
        occurOfW += 1
    index += 1
print(occurOfW)
```

Comment: oh yeah, you have to use .lower() on the string, credit to Clement for showing his answer, honestly, his is better

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lower()` function to make your string lower case at first and then just compare it to the lower case letters.

```
x = "Welcome to this world"
x = x.lower()
list = x.split()
print(list)
a = []

for i in list:
    a.append(i.count("w"))
else:
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `lower()` to transform the text into a lowercase format. After that, split the text and count your desired word.

```
def count_char(text, char):
    text = text.lower()
    char = char.lower()
    words = text.split()
    return [word.count(char) for word in words]


print(count_char("Welcome to this world", "w")) # [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

> **Update:** a compact version of the code above:

```
def count_char(text, char):
    return [word.count(char.lower()) for word in text.lower().split()]


print(count_char("Welcome to this world", "w")) # [1, 0, 0, 1]
```